# Converting date and time based on culture info on WP7

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-7.1, currency, cultureinfo

I'm trying to format the date and time on my app based on the users set culture info, however, every help resource I see keeps suggesting that I have to manually enter each culture locale in code. For example, if I wanted en-UK I would have to manually add new CultureInfo("en-UK"); with something like new CultureInfo("en-UK");.

Is there a way to just tap into the currently set culture on the phone without me having to actually type the rtc culture info in? Something that might work like "date = ConvertToLocalCultureFormat(date);"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this works on WinPhone7, but you could use

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
```

which return the name of the CurrentCulture of the current thread (en-UK or whatever your app runs in)

[See for refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)

However this should not be necessary.
If you convert your datetime to a string in this way:

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  // Converts dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
  string dateInString = dt.ToString("d");
```

you should get the conversion in the right CultureInfo of your phone.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that it might need to be set otherwise since I've read a few articles complaining that it defaults to en-US.

Answer (score 1):

To format anything using the current culture, you don't have to do anything special at all. The overloads of all formatting that doesn't include a specific format or culture uses the default culture.

The `Date.ToString()` method for example will call the overload with `this.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` to pick up the current culture setting of the application and use for the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Which help resources did you read that suggest you have to manually specify the current culture?

The [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) parameterless method automatically uses formatting information derived from the current culture.

> This method uses formatting information derived from the current culture. In particular, it combines the custom format strings returned by the `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` properties of the `DateTimeFormatInfo` object returned by the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` property.

```
DateTime exampleDate = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 18, 32, 6);
string s = exampleDate.ToString();
// Gives "5/1/2008 6:32:06 PM" when the current culture is en-US.
// Gives "01/05/2008 18:32:06" when the current culture is fr-FR.
// Gives "2008/05/01 18:32:06" when the current culture is ja-JP.
```